# config cloud storage and headers for default

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-storage

How to configure that all files, even if they are public, are not cached or how to assign headers by default to all the files that are stored in the cloud storage.

I am uploading files from laravel 5.5.45 using filesystem with the lib Superbalist / laravel-google-cloud-storage and the only thing I can do is assign if the file has a public or private visibility and in private it is not shown to my client side system, then I want to make cloud storage by default when they enter files with public visibility these are not stored in cache because when the client updates the file it takes 1 hour before changing to the new

Comment: By assigning headers, do you mean assigning headers to already stored files?

Comment: Also, Can you elaborate more on your 2nd part of the question?  Is it your requirement, that you want to make file accessible after 1 hour of upload?

Comment: First, please edit your question and enumerate all your inquiries, I can sense there's a lot of questions in there but I can't be sure of where each of them begin and end. Second, I see that you are using a third party lib "Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage" and I can see through their documentation that they don't specify anything about editing the headers of the file when uploading [1] Could you specify what kind of headers you want to edit?.   --- [1]https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage